# QTAgent32.exe, Unhandled Exception Caught, reporting through Watson: System.NullReferenceException

Tags: c#, multithreading, visual-studio, mstest, nullreferenceexception

Presently I am attempting to create unit tests using MSTest.exe for multithreading functionality.  When I run the tests, here are the errors I'm getting:

```
A first chance exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in ApplicationManagement.exe
The thread 'Agent: adapter run thread for test 'UpdateDirectoryExceptionTest' with id 'a78d3e8e-e859-43aa-87aa-cf006f736dee'' (0x1150) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread '<No Name>' (0x1bec) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
E, 6788, 86, 2011/10/20, 14:02:36.771, WKSTVMC0006\QTAgent32.exe, Unhandled Exception Caught, reporting through Watson: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at CommonObjects4.clsThread.StartThreadMethod.Execute() in D:\DevProjects\CommonObjects4\classes\clsThread.cs:line 23
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.runTryCode(Object userData)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.RuntimeHelpers.ExecuteCodeWithGuaranteedCleanup(TryCode code, CleanupCode backoutCode, Object userData)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean ignoreSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
The program '[6788] QTAgent32.exe: Managed (v4.0.30319)' has exited with code -2 (0xfffffffe).
The program '[1120] ApplicationManagement.vshost.exe: Managed (v4.0.30319)' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

If I run the UpdateDirectoryExceptionTest by itself in Visual Studio, it passes with no problem, but when I run the entire suite of unit tests, I receive the above error.  Here is the function that I recently started testing, which I think is related to the error:

```
    public Thread StartClassThread(ref Thread ThreadObject, ThreadMethod MethodObject)
    {
        System.Threading.Thread startClassThreadReturn = null;
        try
        {
            if (ThreadObject == null && MethodObject == null)
            {
                throw new ApplicationException("Cannot have both ThreadObject and MethodObject as null parameters in call to StartClassThread.");
            }
            StartThreadMethod objMethod = new StartThreadMethod();
            objMethod.objThreadMethod = MethodObject;
            if (!(ThreadObject == null))
            {
                if (ThreadObject.ThreadState != System.Threading.ThreadState.Stopped)
                {
                    // Do nothing
                }
            }
            if (!(ThreadObject == null))
            {
                if (ThreadObject.ThreadState == System.Threading.ThreadState.Stopped 
                    | ThreadObject.ThreadState == System.Threading.ThreadState.Aborted
                    | ThreadObject.ThreadState == System.Threading.ThreadState.Unstarted) 
                { 
                    ThreadObject = null; 
                    ThreadObject = new Thread( new System.Threading.ThreadStart( objMethod.Execute ) ); 
                    ThreadObject.Start(); 
                } 
            } 
            else 
            { 
                ThreadObject = new Thread( new System.Threading.ThreadStart( objMethod.Execute ) ); 
                ThreadObject.Start(); 
            } 
            return ThreadObject; 
        } 
        catch (Exception excException) 
        { 
            ZEGApp.clsMain.objApplicationAudit.AuditMethodError(excException, System.Reflection.MethodInfo.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType.FullName + "." + System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name + " - " + excException.StackTrace);
        }
        finally 
        { 
            // Do nothing
        } 
        return startClassThreadReturn;
    }
```

Here is the output I receive from CruiseControl.NET, as opposed to testing within Visual Studio:

```
  <message>Passed                UnitTests.clsThreadTest.StartClassThreadTest2</message>
  <message>Process 'QTAgent32' [PID 3932] has finished profiling.</message>
  <message>Process 'QTAgent32' [PID 5388] has begun profiling.</message>
  <message>Error                 UnitTests.clsUltraCalendarTest.clsUltraCalendarConstructorTest</message>
```

Does anyone have any ideas as to how I can resolve these errors?  TIA.

**UPDATE**: Here is the full source code for clsThread.cs (please note that line 23 is objThreadMethod(); ):

```
namespace CommonObjects4
{
    public class clsThread
    {

    #region '" Sub Class "'

    public delegate void ThreadMethod();

    private class StartThreadMethod  
    { 
        public ThreadMethod objThreadMethod; 
        public void Execute() 
        { 
            objThreadMethod(); // this is line 23
        }
    }

    #endregion

    #region '" Enumerator Declaration "'
    #endregion

    #region '" Variable Declaration "'
    #endregion

    #region '" Property Declaration "'
    #endregion

    #region '" Function Declaration "'

    public Thread StartClassThread(Thread ThreadObject, ThreadMethod MethodObject)
    {
        System.Threading.Thread startClassThreadReturn = null;
        try
        {
            if (ThreadObject == null && MethodObject == null)
            {
                throw new ApplicationException("Cannot have both ThreadObject and MethodObject as null parameters in call to StartClassThread.");
            }
            StartThreadMethod objMethod = new StartThreadMethod();
            objMethod.objThreadMethod = MethodObject;
            if (!(ThreadObject == null))
            {
                if (ThreadObject.ThreadState != System.Threading.ThreadState.Stopped)
                {
                    // Do nothing
                }
            }
            if (!(ThreadObject == null))
            {
                if (ThreadObject.ThreadState == System.Threading.ThreadState.Stopped | ThreadObject.ThreadState == System.Threading.ThreadState.Aborted ) 
                { 
                    ThreadObject = null; 
                    ThreadObject = new Thread( new System.Threading.ThreadStart( objMethod.Execute ) ); 
                    ThreadObject.Start(); 
                } 
            } 
            else 
            { 
                ThreadObject = new Thread( new System.Threading.ThreadStart( objMethod.Execute ) ); 
                ThreadObject.Start(); 
            } 
            return ThreadObject; 
        } 
        catch (Exception excException) 
        { 
            ZEGApp.clsMain.objApplicationAudit.AuditMethodError(excException, System.Reflection.MethodInfo.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType.FullName + "." + System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name + " - " + excException.StackTrace);
        }
        finally 
        { 
            // Do nothing
        } 
        return startClassThreadReturn;
    } 

    #endregion 

} 
}
```

Comment: What's at line 23 in D:\DevProjects\CommonObjects4\classes\clsThread.cs?  (It would probably help if you could add the full StartThreadMethod.Execute() method body or, even better, the complete StartThreadMethod class definition.)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, Nicole.  Please see the clsThread.cs code above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem would appear to be that `objThreadMethod` is null at line 23.  The syntax `objThreadMethod()` is actually shorthand for `objThreadMethod.Invoke()`, so you'll get a `NullReferenceException` if `objThreadMethod` is null when the line is executed.

As for why it's null, I'm guessing that you've invoked the `StartClassThread` method with a non-null `ThreadObject` and a null `MethodObject`, which resulted in the following block being executed after setting `objMethod.objThreadMethod` to the null `MethodObject`:

```
ThreadObject = null;
ThreadObject = new Thread( new System.Threading.ThreadStart( objMethod.Execute ) );
ThreadObject.Start();
```

Comment: Yes, one of the tests I'm writing is explicitly sending in a null value to ensure it handles it properly.  Shouldn't the exception be caught by the "catch (Exception excException)" code, rather than causing the whole unit test suite to terminate abruptly and prematurely?

Comment: Exceptions are not automatically propagated between threads.  The exception is occurring in a separate thread from the catch block.  If you want to catch and log exceptions in the spawned background thread, you would need to add a wrapping try/catch in the StartThreadMethod.Execute() method.  Otherwise, an exception on the background thread will bring down your process.  (That said, I wouldn't necessarily agree that systematically preventing an otherwise unhandled exception on a background thread from bringing down the process is usually the best idea in the world.)

Answer (score 1):

I think that for starters, you want to configure the tests to run with the multi-threaded apartment:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404663.aspx

I'd try that and see if you continue to have exceptions.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, however, after adding <ExecutionThread apartmentState="MTA" /> it still crashes at the same point. It runs 360 of the 375 tests and then the rest of the test fail. If I take out the threading unit tests, then all the tests pass.  Hmmm...